# TypeScript - how to use an index on a variable type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to pass a string index to use on one of two state types. It throws the following error:

```
    type Index = 'name' | 'length' | 'width' | 'depth' | 'height'
    
    interface StateOne {
        name: string
        length: number
    }
    
    interface StateTwo {
        width: number
        depth: number
        height: number
    }
    
    interface SwitchProps {
        state: StateOne | StateTwo
        index: Index
    }
    
    function testFunction({state, index}: SwitchProps) {
        const test = state[index]
    }
    
//TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'Index' can't be used to index type 'StateOne | StateTwo'. 
//Property 'name' does not exist on type 'StateOne | StateTwo'.
```

How would you write this to get around the problem?

This works, but it is a bad workaround:

```
const test = state[index as unknown as keyof typeof state]
```

Comment: `state[index].name` looks wrong. `'name'` would be passed through `index`, no?

Comment: Yes, missed that. I've updated it. 'name' is the first property in the index where it encounters a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [generics and restrict](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#using-type-parameters-in-generic-constraints) `index` to be a valid key of `state`:

```
function testFunction<K extends keyof T, T>({ state, index }: { state: T, index: K }) {
  return state[index]
}

declare const state1: StateOne;
declare const state2: StateTwo;

testFunction({ state: state1, index: 'name' }) // string
testFunction({ state: state2, index: 'width' }) // number

// Error: Type '"width"' is not assignable to type 'keyof StateOne'
testFunction({ state: state1, index: 'width' })
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpjpA8iFBvAWAChlkQ4BbCALmQGcwpQBzY0gGwhGbAAtaQAVwoAjaMQC%20xYqEixEKdJggAVAO4B7ZIRLI1wACZ8BwsVDbIDEAA7Gyp8bt4RgzXmBOjHUosRiCQBDBgDRBkSAYAMQCgkJAAHgBpZAgAD0gQAzpkAGsIAE8NGGQVABoSgD4ACjx6DEhy0CtU5AlaWoZlWjLkJrTaZIkASm0LKAgwQSgwzsgAbT7UgF1JaSIrBHY4ceQEUIY65QBGWiVsXABuYg2tnb2QA9mIACZT%20tVNK98iCLBowOCoRqh0gtCeR0amX6yAA5OQqDDWiMAPTIupMbjEX7-WJAjrvMHvZ6Q5q0GH6Iy8RHDZCo%20xeczfOkAUSgUA0UG6%20WsKBhACIKXw%20YjgNkQBowMg4HQ6K5yCJOOEtGBuby8oVimcIDgIDCsRAojFASBgU9CccSdDyYY%20NShkA)

Comment: You can change the function's generic to `<K extends keyof T, T extends StateOne | StateTwo>` to strictly type the `state` parameter

Comment: Yeah, but no reason to do so

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) to discriminate between your types:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ssl=31&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpjpA8iFBvAWAChlkQ4BbCALmQGcwpQBzAbmNIBsIRmwALWiACuFAEbR2RAL7FioSLEQp0mCABUA7gHtkEAB6QQAEzrIAShATaoxgDwByYxAAOAh8gA+yB-wjBmfjAPbwdNYGN3ABoyUQkoAD5kPFkiYjAATxcUAAUobRcANTgmOHA7dSSAXmSOegxIWnUpUlBnfVoAawgM7RhkZuJpKXSslXCwBH48grMamaKS4DKwO1VsXCTvBeLS8vWNHQSRohhhEAQwYG0QZGA6A5wUAAoXfJc6WlQJqYW6AEpaG9ZnczDslis1g0IE8koQSMgAPQAKmRyAABgAichUTHo5A3TgZPT6e5gMygNA-fhPGJ0XTAfoCe7IKAQMDCKAgMzoxjCCDomKaFCdEDaTR3YJmASYZCZbLIZGIupsjlcnw4iAeSnAj4AOgYaikqWIZwuVxucogDAAYudLtdbq93p8qcBJtMXYDkAA3bQRWoIxnIZ73R64Z2zf7-QOkUjWblgX1wTj85A1XV0A3QgDamb1bQMAF1WEjEfUmLwvLFxNA6vGbvTuHrONpmM8fSn+f8WnGEwxktxeAJpOnkPnDZBS4jywxK8w6qlSBBOHR8PXkP2k53UygMy7s2o8wfC-oS2Wa-EN-3tM3W+2d93ew3E8lnG5+KP97ND1OLyJaygRchmIIA)

```ts
interface StateOne {
  name: string;
  length: number;
}

interface StateTwo extends Record<'depth' | 'height' | 'width', number> {}

type PropVariant<T> = {
  state: T;
  index: keyof T;
};

type SwitchProps = PropVariant<StateOne> | PropVariant<StateTwo>;

function isStateOne (props: SwitchProps): props is PropVariant<StateOne> {
  /** `"name"` only exists in SwitchOne, so if this returns `true`, we know it's that type */
  return 'name' in props.state;
}

function testFunction (props: SwitchProps): void {
  if (isStateOne(props)) {
    const value = props.state[props.index]; // string | number
    console.log(value);
    const {length} = props.state; // string
  }
  else {
    const value = props.state[props.index]; // number
    console.log(value);
    const {depth} = props.state; // number
  }
}
```